# Abstract factory pattern: why we need Abstract Product Interface

Tags: design-patterns, abstract-factory

We know that, following classes are needed to design Abstract factory pattern:

- AbstractFactory
- ConcreteFactory
- AbstractProduct
- Product

My question is why we need **AbstractProduct** ? Look the following  code where i created Abstract factory pattern without any AbstractProduct:

```
<?php

abstract class AbstractFactory
{
    abstract public function createProduct(string $content);
}

class Factory extends AbstractFactory
{
    public function createProduct(string $content)
    {
        return new Product($content);
    }
}

class Product
{
    private $text;

    public function __construct(string $text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function getText(){
        return $this->text;
    }
}


$factory = new Factory();
$product = $factory->createProduct('foobar');
echo $product ->getText();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A Factory produces some Products.*

You can see quite a few similar things:

- A Car Factory produces Cars.
- A Milk Factory produces some Milk.
- and so on.

That's it. AbstractProduct is applicable when you have multiple type of products. In the example above, Product can be either Car or Milk. If you only have one kind of product, you don't need to define AbstractProduct, as the pattern does not encourage you to make Product abstract. Just only AbstractFactory is needed.